# Why can I not delete roads from my list of roads?

Tags: python, list, graph

Why won't this delete items from my list of Road objects?

Relevant info

Road objects take (self, city1, city2, length), and City objects take (self, name, population);

I am saving these objects into a lists _cities and _roads so that I can modify them.

This definition is supposed to delete any roads attached to a city and then delete the city.

However, my code doesn't want to delete my roads (and I get no errors) so my logic must be flawed.

Can you help?

```
class Network:

    def __init__(self):

        self._cities = []  # list of City objects in this network
        self._roads = []   # list of Road objects in this network

    def hasCity(self, name):

        for x in self._cities:
            if x.name == name:
                return True
        return False

    def hasRoad(self, road):

        for x in self._roads:
            if x.city1 == road[0] and x.city2 == road[1]:
                return True
            elif x.city1 == road[1] and x.city2 == road[0]:
                return True
            else:
                return False

    def addCity(self, name, pop):
        if self.hasCity(name) == True:
            return False
        else:
            self._cities.append(City(name, pop))
            return True

    def addRoad(self, road, length):

        if self.hasRoad(road) == True:
            return False
        else:
            self._roads.append(Road(road[0], road[1], length))
            return True

    def delRoad(self, road):
        if self.hasRoad(road) == False:
            return False
        else:
            for x in self._roads:
                if x.city1 == road[0] and x.city2 == road[1]:
                    self._roads.remove(x)
                    return True
                elif x.city1 == road[1] and x.city2 == road[0]:
                    self._roads.remove(x)
                    return True
                else:
                    return False


    def delCity(self, city):

        if self.hasCity(city) == False:
            return False
        else:
            for x in self._cities:
                if x.name == city:
                    for j in self._roads:
                        if j.city1 == x.name:
                            self.delRoad((j.city1, j.city2))
                            self.delRoad((j.city2, j.city1))
                        elif j.city2 == x.name:
                            self.delRoad((j.city1, j.city2))
                            self.delRoad((j.city2, j.city1))
                    self._cities.remove(x)
                    return True
```

Comment: Can you maybe put in the whole class?

Comment: You could rephrase the question to say "how to delete edges of an undirected graph."

Comment: The deeply nested `if` blocks seem redundant; they could be together in an `if j.city1 == x.name or j.city2 == x.name:` clause

Comment: Hey editor, who says there are no cycles in the graph?

Comment: just updated it to include the whole class.  What does this have to do with graphs, btw?

Comment: Thanks @JessetheGame, that's a good point.

Comment: @TylerSeymour: It has to do with graphs in the sense of [graph theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory). Your cities are the "nodes" of the graph and your roads are the "edges".

Comment: BTW, if _cities and _roads were dicts, it would simplify your del* functions a lot.  For _roads, you could use tuples of city1/city2 as the key.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is probably that you delete an element of a list on which you iterate.
This is generally a bad practice.

Comment: While that generally is a bad practice, he says that the roads are deleted.  The roads would be deleted before city removal is attempted.

Comment: Vkontori, I checked it and I think @Joshua D. Boyd is right - I don't see where I would have done this (unless you do?!)

Comment: Your bug is in hasRoad it will not check all roads, instead it will return false if the first one does not match.

Comment: To fix it you should return False, outside the for loop. Then the whole thing should work...

Comment: vkontori - genius!  Thanks.  What an eye!

Answer (score 0):

delCity is could be improved, but it seems to work fine.  I believe you need to post more code. I worked up sample code to test delCity.  Here is the City class:

```
class City(object):
    def __init__(self, name, population):
        self.name = name
        self.population = population

    def __repr__(self):
        return "City(%r, %r)" % (self.name, self.population)
```

Here is the Road class:

```
class Road(object):
    def __init__ (self, city1, city2, length):
        self.city1 = city1
        self.city2 = city2
        self.length = length

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Road(%r, %r, %r)" % (self.city1, self.city2, self.length)
```

Here is the Test class that I pasted you delCity method into:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, cities, roads):
        self._cities = cities
        self._roads = roads

    def hasCity(self, city_name):
        for c in self._cities:
            if c.name == city_name:
                return True
        return False

    def delRoad(self, pair):
        for x in self._roads:
            if x.city1 == pair[0] and x.city2 == pair[1]:
                self._roads.remove(x)

    def delCity(self, city):
        if self.hasCity(city) == False: #checks to see if city isn't in list
            return False
        else:
            for x in self._cities:
                if x.name == city:
                    for j in self._roads:
                        if j.city1 == x.name:
                            self.delRoad((j.city1, j.city2)) ##delRoad takes a tuple
                            self.delRoad((j.city2, j.city1))
                        elif j.city2 == x.name:
                            self.delRoad((j.city1, j.city2))
                            self.delRoad((j.city2, j.city1))
                    self._cities.remove(x)
                    return True
```

And here I now test your code:

```
>>> t = Test([City('x', 1), City('y', 1), City('z', 1)],
             [Road('x', 'y', 1), Road('y', 'z', 1)])
>>> t.delCity('x')

>>> print t._cities
[City('y', 1), City('z', 1)]
>>> print t._roads
[Road('y', 'z', 1)]
```

As you can see, the city and single road that went to that city was deleted.

Comment: Hmm, I'll keep debugging.  Thanks for checking that for me.  I'll post back when I start banging my head against the wall again.